# Vertical and horizontal alignment (Boostrap 4)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align text and button vertically as well as horizontally and cannot make it...
What I want ultimately is that alignment was responsive.
My code:
HTML:

```
    <div id="stage">
    <div id="stage-caption">
      <h1 class="display-3">Gallery Nellija</h1>
      <p>Some description</p>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Sign up now</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#stage {
    background: url('img/stage.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#stage-caption {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    max-width: 60rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#stage-caption h1 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

For now it looks like that:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align:center` to `#stage`